# REQ/REP & DEALER/ROUTER for two-way asynchronous worker processing

Tags: zeromq

I'm learning ZeroMQ and just went through the tutorial and a few examples. I'm using Node.js as my main environment ( with Python eventually used to replace my workers ).

Trying to sort out how I can create a fully asynchronous messaging system that will allow my API to push tasks ( via a **`REQ`** socket ) to a router, have a dealer pass the message to a worker, process the message and send its results back up to my client ( which is an Express route ).

I believe the pattern for this would work something like this ( haven't tested or properly implemented code yet, so please take it as a conceptual outline ):

---

router.js

```
const zmq = require('zmq');;
const frontend = zmq.socket('router');
const backend = zmq.socket('dealer');

frontend.on('message', function() {
  var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
  backend.send(args);
});
backend.on('message', function() {
  var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
  frontend.send(args);
});

frontend.bindSync('tcp://*:5559');
backend.bindSync('tcp://*:5560');
```

---

client.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq'),
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('send', function(req, res) {
  var client = zmq.socket('req');
  // listen for responses from the server 
  client.on('message', function(data) {  
     console.log(data);
     client.close();
  }); 
  // connect to the server port 
  client.connect('tcp://0.0.0.0:5454');  
  client.send('Request from ' + process.id);
});
app.listen('80');
```

---

worker.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var server = zmq.socket('rep');

server.on('message', function(d){  
  server.send('Response from ' + process.id); 
}); 
// bind to port 5454 
server.bind('tcp://0.0.0.0:5454', function(err){  
  if (err){ 
    console.error("something bad happened"); 
    console.error( err.msg ); 
    console.error( err.stack ); 
    process.exit(0); 
  } 
});
```

---

What I'm not fully understanding is if the **`ROUTER/DEALER`** will handle sending the response worker to the correct client. Also in this case the Dealer handles the Fair Queueing as I want my work distributed amongst the workers evenly.

My client could be distributed amongst many different boxes ( load balancer API server ), my router will be on its own server and the workers would be distributed amongst multiple boxes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Forget `REQ/REP` in any production-grade app, can fall in mutual deadlock

You might find this subject in many other posts on high-risk mutual FSM-FSM deadlocking in `REQ/REP` Formal Scalable Communication Pattern.

---

### Be sure, `XREQ/XREP == DEALER/ROUTER`  <sup>( already since 2011 )</sup>

source code removes all hidden magics behind this, **`XREQ == DEALER`** and **`XREP == ROUTER`**

```
+++b/include/zmq.h
...
-#define ZMQ_XREQ 5
-#define ZMQ_XREP 6
+#define ZMQ_DEALER 5
+#define ZMQ_ROUTER 6
...
+#define ZMQ_XREQ ZMQ_DEALER        /*  Old alias, remove in 3.x     */
+#define ZMQ_XREP ZMQ_ROUTER        /*  Old alias, remove in 3.x     */
```

Comment: How would I avoid the mutual deadlock then? Can you perhaps suggest an alternative method to the pattern I've presented?

Comment: Deadlock is unavoidable + unsalvageable. Just never use `REQ/REP`.

Comment: Ok that's concerning. How about using REP-PUB for the client and REQ-SUB for the worker? The broker would use DEALER and ROUTER. Does that potentially solve the issue? If not what pattern makes most sense here?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this in the future, in my further research I stumbled on the Majordomo Protocol/pattern. It's precisely what I'm trying to implement. Documentation on the implementation, benefits and disadvantages can be read here: https://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:18/MDP/. Here's the broker implementation: https://github.com/zeromq/majordomo

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was using **`DEALER/ROUTER`** when I should have been using **`XREQ`** and **`XREP`**.

broker.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var frontPort = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5559';
var backPort = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5560';

var frontSocket = zmq.socket('xrep');
var backSocket = zmq.socket('xreq');

frontSocket.identity = 'xrep_' + process.pid;
backSocket.identity = 'xreq_' + process.pid;

frontSocket.bind(frontPort, function (err) {
    console.log('bound', frontPort);
});

frontSocket.on('message', function() {
  //pass to back
  console.log('router: sending to server', arguments[0].toString(), arguments[2].toString());
  backSocket.send(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
});

backSocket.bind(backPort, function (err) {
  console.log('bound', backPort);
});

backSocket.on('message', function() {
  //pass to front
  console.log('dealer: sending to client', arguments[0].toString(), arguments[2].toString());
  frontSocket.send(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
});

console.log('Broker started...');
```

worker.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var socket = zmq.socket('rep');

socket.identity = 'worker_' + process.pid;

socket.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log(socket.identity + ': received ' + data.toString());
    socket.send(data * 2);
});
socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5560', function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('server connected!');
});

console.log('Worker started...');
```

client.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var socket = zmq.socket('req');

socket.identity = 'client_' + process.pid;

socket.on('message', function(data) {
  console.log(socket.identity + ': answer data ' + data);
});
socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5559');

setInterval(function() {
  var value = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
  console.log(socket.identity + ': asking ' + value);
  socket.send(value);
}, 100);

console.log('Client started...');
```

I'm still not sure if it's safe opening a connection on EVERY API inbound request.

Comment: It is always a bad idea to setup + tear-down the ZeroMQ messaging / signalling infrastructure upon each call. ZeroMQ is by far not a consumable / disposable, you devastate a lot of system overheads per each call + pay a lot in waiting additional latencies, before all the infrastructure components reach an RTO-state End-to-End. Bad idea even for school-book examples. Do not ever promote such ill-motivated programming style.

Comment: That was my precise thought and concern. The question then is how would I map requests for the sockets so that the correct route receives the response msg?